# PFQuery includeKey on array of dictionaries.

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, parse-platform, pfquery, key-value-coding

I have a `parse` class with a `NSArray` column, it is an `array` of `dictionaries`, and inside that `dictionary`I have a `key` with a `pointer` to another class. I'm trying to use `includeKey` but it is not working. I'm hoping to get the `objects` inside `pointers` without calling `fetch`, since there are many, the `requests` could go up easily.

I'm using: `[query includeKey:@"ingredients.item"];` Ingredients is an `NSArray` of `dictionaries`, it is a column in the main object. item is a `key` in the `dictionary` that stores `pointers`.

```
[{"item":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"NutricaoCatalogo","objectId":"aTnHD5ttUH"},"ingredientTitle":"Clara De Ovo Natural","portionIndex":"1","portionQuantity":200},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ingredients"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error && objects) {
        for(int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {
            PFObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
            PFObject *pointer = [[object valueForKey:@"item"] valueForKey:@"__type"];

            PFObject *obj = [PFQuery getObjectOfClass:@"<classname of that pointer points to>" objectId:(NSString *)pointer];

            //obj is an object of that pointer so you can manupulate accordingly
            //Note: getObjectOfClass: objectId: method run on main thread
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

include only works on pointers. It doesn't even work on an array of pointers.

One point I want to make first is that unless you have a ton of active users, you're not going to hit the mark for free requests any time soon. If you are, your app should be profitable enough that it doesn't matter.

My best solution would be to call a background job that performs a `query.each()` and pulls all of the object ids that you'd like to get, then returns the array of objectIds. Then, you can query for all the objects with ids that are `containedIn` that array.

Comment: Include does work on array of pointers. I'm using includeKey on an array of pointers in my project at the moment and it works great, no extra fetching required.

Comment: This must work differently in the iOS SDK than it does in the JS SDK. In JS, the .include() method did not retrieve all of the pointers in my array for me. I have not tested a similar functionality on iOS. I went straight to pulling the array and using PFObject fetchAll